# Prometheus not Scraping Custom Metrics (prometheus_demo_request_total) from ASP.NET Core Application with OpenTelemetry

Tags: prometheus, middleware, open-telemetry, asp.net-core-middleware

I have implemented a custom middleware in my ASP.NET Core application to log HTTP request metrics using Prometheus. I implemented the middleware using the [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reporting-metrics-to-prometheus-in-asp-net-core/). However, despite the middleware being triggered for each HTTP request, these custom metrics are not appearing when accessing the /metrics endpoint.

I have confirmed that the counter.Labels(...).Inc() calls are executed during the middleware's invocation, but the expected metrics are missing in the Prometheus metrics output. Other default metrics from OpenTelemetry are present.

I seek assistance in identifying the root cause of this issue and ensuring that the custom metrics are correctly scraped and displayed by Prometheus.

My Startup.cs class looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                .WithMetrics(builder => builder
                    .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                    .AddPrometheusExporter());
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, CustomDbContext dbContext, ILogger<RedactableDbContext> logger)
{
    app.UseRequestMiddleware();

    ...
}
```

The following are the libraries that I am using for OpenTelemetry and Prometheus:

```
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore" Version="1.6.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.5.1-beta.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.5.1-beta.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.RunTime" Version="1.5.1" />
<PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="8.2.0" />
```

Comment: Not familiar with this specific implementation, but it's common for custom metrics to be "registered" in metrics registry, to be later exposed on metrics page. Could it be that you missed that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom metrics need to be registered with the OpenTelemetry SDK.

Modify your existing setup code to include a call to `AddMeter`:

```
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithMetrics(builder => builder
        .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddPrometheusExporter());
        .AddMeter("YourMeterName"));
```

Without this, the Prometheus exporter will not be aware of your custom metric.